# How to use grep to find all instances of one .txt file in another?

Tags: terminal, grep

How would I use grep to compare if any line from one .txt document occurred in another?

Further how would I use grep to find out the opposite? Would it be `grep -v`?

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -F -f inner_file outer_file
```

Explanation of the parameters from the documentation for [GNU grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html):

> `-F`,
>   `--fixed-strings`
>
> Interpret the pattern as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched. (`-F` is specified by POSIX.)
>
> `-f file`,
>   `--file=file`
>
> Obtain patterns from file, one per line. The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing. (`-f` is specified by POSIX.)

You might also want to use the `-x` option:

> `-x`,
>   `--line-regexp`
>
> Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line. (`-x` is specified by POSIX.)

Add the `-v` option to find out the opposite:

> `-v`,
>   `--invert-match`
>
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines. (`-v` is specified by POSIX.)

Quick test using the Bash shell:

```
# grep -F -f <(printf 'A\nZ\n') <(printf 'A\nB\nC\n')
A
# echo $?
0
# grep -F -f <(printf 'A\nZ\n') <(printf 'B\nC\n')
# echo $?
1
# grep -v -F -f <(printf 'A\nZ\n') <(printf 'B\nC\n')
B
C
# echo $?
0
# grep -x -F -f <(printf 'A\nZ\n') <(printf 'AA\nBB\nCC\n')
# echo $?
1
```

Comment: Add the `-x` option if you want exact match as opposed to substring match.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested something similar to your problem and concluded with this:

`cat sampleOne.txt | cat sampleTwo.txt | grep <pattern>`

For example I had this written in the text files:

```
This is a test.
1111
2222
```

When I looked specifically for "This is a test", I have used

`cat *.txt | grep "This is a test."`

```
This is a test.
This is a test.
```

or

`cat sampleOne.txt && cat sampleTwo.txt | grep "This is a test."`

Result:

```
This is a test.
11111
22222
This is a test.
```

or even

`cat sampleOne.txt | cat sampleTwo.txt | grep "This is a test"`

which got me:

`This is a test.`

The command `grep -v pattern` will of course find the inverse of the pattern you are looking for. For example

`cat *.txt | grep -v "This is a test."`

Will give me:

```
11111
22222
11111
22222
```

Comment: `cat sampleOne.txt | cat sampleTwo.txt` doesn't make sense because the first command (or better said the contents of `sampleOne.txt`) makes no difference.

Comment: I was experimenting with several commands that can be used. I wasn't too sure of `cat sampleOne.txt | cat sampleTwo.txt` though